# Using p5 library and the CreateCanvas function, how can you make the canvas create inside a div class?

Tags: javascript, html, function, processing, p5.js

How can i place the canvas inside a div tag?
It always creates at the bottom of the body in the html and i want to put it inside a div.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  audioContext = getAudioContext();
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start(listening);
}
```

i tried putting the function in the html under a div however it sill placed the canvas outside the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`createCanvas()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas) returns *p5.Renderer*. You can attach the canvas to a [`parent()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/parent) element:

```html
<div id="my_canvas"></div>
```

```js
let my_canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
my_canvas.parent('my_canvas')
```